# syntax error codepen full view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to complete the wikipedia search for freecodecamp,(in codepen), and i'm running into this problem where my code will run in codepen's edit view and debug view, but fails to run in, "details view",and "full view". The error given in the console in details, and full view, is,

"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

, yet jshint can't seem to find the error, and the code seems to run fine otherwise? Is it simply a codepen bug?

Here is my pen. Very sketchy. :o

https://codepen.io/ohrha/pen/wgZYvM?editors=1000 (editor view)(working)
https://codepen.io/ohrha/full/wgZYvM/ (full view)(not working)

```
    $.ajax ({
              type:'GET',
              url: prefixSearch,
              dataType:'jsonp',
              success: function(jason){
                     var prefixSearchResults= jason;
                     console.log(prefixSearchResults.query.prefixsearch.length);
                     console.log(prefixSearchResults.query.prefixsearch[0].pageid);
                     console.log(prefixSearchResults.query.prefixsearch[0].title);


                     for(var i= 0; i<prefixSearchResults.query.prefixsearch.length;i++){
                     curid.push( "https://crossorigin.me/https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&exchars=175&explaintext&pageids="+prefixSearchResults.query.prefixsearch[i].pageid);  queryResultsArray.push(prefixSearchResults.query.prefixsearch[i].pageid);
               queryResultUrls.push("<a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer"href= 'https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid="+prefixSearchResults.query.prefixsearch[i].pageid+">"+prefixSearchResults.query.prefixsearch[i].title+"</a><br>"+prefixSearchResults); 

//here the "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" error occurs.
                       extracts.push(prefixSearchResults.query.prefixsearch[i].pageid);
                       console.log(extracts);
                     }
                     }});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you quotes are mixed up `"` and `'` in your `queryResultUrls.push( here )`

Comment: Ahh thanks. Can i not use a combination? Or is escaping my only option?

Comment: combination is fine. If you start and end tag with `" "` you can use `' '` inside, and vice versa if you start and end with `' '` can use `" "`  insde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to escaping the quotes like @subwaymatch pointed out, you could just use single quotes here

```
queryResultHrefLink='<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid='+prefixSearchResults.query.prefixsearch[i].pageid+'">'+prefixSearchResults.query.prefixsearch[i].title+'</a><br>'+prefixSearchResults;
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! *pounds*

Comment: @trigramthree awesome, you're welcome :) *\*pound\**

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the " (double quotes) inside the queryResultUrls.push().

```
queryResultUrls.push("<a rel=\"nofollow\" rel=\"noreferrer\" href= 'https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid="+prefixSearchResults.query.prefixsearch[i].pageid+">"+prefixSearchResults.query.prefixsearch[i].title+"</a><br>"+prefixSearchResults);
```

Comment: Yea, a combination of both my improper useage of single and double quotes, and lack of escapes for my double quotes when corrected. The "rel= "no follow" and rel="no referrer" only appears in my console view actually, i accidentally posted that version.